# Wordpress Login and Register Link

Tags: login

I am finding difficulty in returning the wp_login_form() and register link at the same time.

Here is my code which i am working to make shortcode. How to send the login_form and ***register link*** if user is ***not logged in***?

```
function add_login_form() {
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        return wp_login_form();
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function [`wp_register`](http://look4wp.com/wp_register) will display the register link if the user isn't logged in.

Edit:

Here's the code:

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() )
{
    return wp_login_form( 'echo=0' ) . wp_register( '', '', false );
}
```

Comment: I tried using wp_register() in the above code but after adding it box disappeared. :/

Comment: Just updated the code with example

Comment: That's an invalid shortcode, shortcodes expect their html returned, you're not meant to output it directly during the function

Comment: @TomJNowell, thanks. Just updated the code. I didn't notice the 'shortcode' :).

Answer (score 1):

Your shortcode is already broken. `wp_login_form` doesn't return a html string containing a login form. Instead it prints it out directly to the screen.

Instead do this:

```
function add_login_form() {
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        $html = wp_login_form(array('echo'=>false)).' '.wp_register('','',false);
        return $html;
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

I've added [`wp_register`](http://look4wp.com/wp_register) to add the registration link, and I've also modified the arguments to return rather than echo out the markup

Comment: Hi tom, is it possible to add link this way? <a href="http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=register">Register</a>

Comment: Have you actually read my answer? It adds a registration link as asked.

Comment: I have actually tested your code. When i run that shortcode it shows nothing on the page than loginbox. So that is why I asked that question. :/

Comment: It does work, wp_register only returns a value if registration is allowed. Go into your settings and turn it on